# Lambda Python Pool.map and urllib2.urlopen : Retry only failing processes, log only errors

Tags: python, lambda, urllib2

I have an AWS Lambda function which calls a set of URLs using `pool.map`.  The problem is that if one of the URLs returns anything other than a `200` the Lambda function fails and immediately retries.  The problem is it immediately retries the ENTIRE lambda function.  I'd like it to retry only the failed URLs, and if (after a second try) it still fails them, call a fixed URL to log an error.

This is the code as it currently sits (with some details removed), working only when all URLs are:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import urllib2 
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

import hashlib
import datetime
import json

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  f = urllib2.urlopen("https://example.com/geturls/?action=something");
  data = json.loads(f.read());

  urls = [];
  for d in data:
      urls.append("https://"+d+".example.com/path/to/action");

  # Make the Pool of workers
  pool = ThreadPool(4);

  # Open the urls in their own threads
  # and return the results
  results = pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls);

  #close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
  pool.close();
  return pool.join();
```

I tried reading [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) but it seems to be lacking a bit in explaining the `map` function, specifically explaining return values.

Using the [urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) documentation I've tried modifying my code to the following:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import urllib2 
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

import hashlib
import datetime
import json

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

  f = urllib2.urlopen("https://example.com/geturls/?action=something");
  data = json.loads(f.read());

  urls = [];
  for d in data:
      urls.append("https://"+d+".example.com/path/to/action");

  # Make the Pool of workers
  pool = ThreadPool(4);

  # Open the urls in their own threads
  # and return the results
  try:
     results = pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls);
  except URLError:
     try:                              # try once more before logging error
        urllib2.urlopen(URLError.url); # TODO: figure out which URL errored
     except URLError:                  # log error
        urllib2.urlopen("https://example.com/error/?url="+URLError.url);

  #close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
  pool.close();
  return true; # always return true so we never duplicate successful calls
```

I'm not sure if I'm correct to be doing exceptions that way, or if I'm even making python exception notation correctly.  Again, my goal is **I'd like it to retry only the failed URLs, and if (after a second try) it still fails them, call a fixed URL to log an error.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer thanks to [a "lower-level" look at this question I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643380/python-how-to-know-which-url-is-failing-using-urllib2-and-pool-map).

The answer was to create my own custom wrapper to the `urllib2.urlopen` function, since each thread itself needed to be *try{}catch*'d instead of the whole thing.  That function looked like so:

```
def my_urlopen(url):
    try:
        return urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except URLError:
        urllib2.urlopen("https://example.com/log_error/?url="+url)
        return None
```

I put that above the `def lambda_handler` function declaration, then I can replace the whole try/catch within it from this:

```
try:
   results = pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls);
except URLError:
   try:                              # try once more before logging error
      urllib2.urlopen(URLError.url);
   except URLError:                  # log error
      urllib2.urlopen("https://example.com/error/?url="+URLError.url);
```

To this:

```
results = pool.map(my_urlopen, urls);
```

Q.E.D.